# Terraform GCP Instance Schedules: Add Instance to schedule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am new to coding / terraform. Trying to add a VM with the instance schedule created.

Do I need to update the code below to add a VM or do something else?

```
resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "weekly" {
  project = local.test_project_id
  name   = "test-start-stop-schedule-1"
  region = var.region
  description = "Start and stop instances"
  instance_schedule_policy {
    vm_start_schedule {
      schedule = "30 5 * * 1,2,3,4,5"
    }
    vm_stop_schedule {
      schedule = "0 20 * * 1,2,3,4,5"
    }
    time_zone = "US/Eastern"
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's a very weird way to attach these two things together

Apparently, you need `google_compute_instance` defined and in this resource block there is a parameter of `resource_policies` you need to add a self-link to this parameter of the instance schedule you have created

The worst part of this is that the moment you remove this attachment from the `google_compute_instance` it will recreate the VM for some reason

Comment: I think it's no longer the case. I've used it and either changing `resource_policies` or removing it, it's only triggering and in-place update.

Answer (score 0):

Your Terraform code only defines a Policy resource. To make use of it, you need code for a VM resource and a policy attachment resource between the Policy and the VM.

Example:

```
resource "google_compute_disk_resource_policy_attachment" "attachment" {
  name = google_compute_resource_policy.policy.name
  disk = google_compute_disk.ssd.name
  zone = "us-central1-a"
}
```

Please check completed code at [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_disk_resource_policy_attachment#example-usage---disk-resource-policy-attachment-basic).